# How create a pine script that places buy/sell signals on chart when the MFI is above 50 AND the DMI+ crosses the DMI-

Tags: pine-script

I have no idea what I am doing and the idea seems simple to code, but I have no experience doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Morning Brad Standige,

Please see below. Does this answer you question:

```
//@version=4
study("StackOverFlow", shorttitle="SOF", overlay=false, format=format.price)

//////////////////// Money Flow Index Start

// Input
mfi_period = input(14, title="MFI Period", minval=1)
mfi_upper = input(80, title="Upper Treshold Line", minval=1)
mfi_middle = input(50, title="Upper Treshold Line", minval=1)
mfi_lower = input(20, title="Lower Treshold Line", minval=1)


// Calculates the money flow index value. 
calc_mfi(len) =>
    tp = nz(hlc3)  // typical price
    pos_mf = sum(change(tp) > 0 ? tp : 0, len) * volume // pos. money flow
    neg_mf = sum(change(tp) < 0 ? tp : 0, len) * volume // neg. money flow
    mr = pos_mf / neg_mf // money ratio
    mfi = 100 - (100 / (1 + mr))
    mfi

mfi_val = calc_mfi(mfi_period)


// Drawings
plot(mfi_val, title="MFI", color=color.teal, linewidth=2)
plotshape(mfi_val, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.teal,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="MFI", transp=0, title="MFI")

hline(mfi_upper, title="Upper Treshold", color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_dotted, linewidth=2)
hline(mfi_middle, title="Middle Treshold", color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_dotted, linewidth=2)
hline(mfi_lower, title="Lower Treshold", color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_dotted, linewidth=2)

//////////////////// Money Flow Index Finish

//////////////////// DMI Start

// Input
len = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)
th = input(title="Threshold", type=input.integer, defval=20)

// Calculates DMI value. 
TrueRange = max(max(high - low, abs(high - nz(close[1]))), abs(low - nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high - nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1]) - low ? max(high - nz(high[1]), 0) : 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1]) - low > high - nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1]) - low, 0) : 0

SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) / len + TrueRange
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - 
   nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) / len + DirectionalMovementPlus
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - 
   nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) / len + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100

// Drawings
plot(DIPlus, color=color.green, title="DI+", transp=0)
plotshape(DIPlus, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.green,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="DIPlus", transp=0, title="DIPlus")

plot(DIMinus, color=color.red, title="DI-", transp=0)
plotshape(DIMinus, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.red,  textcolor=color.white, show_last=1, text="DIMinus", transp=0, title="DIMinus")



// Visual Alerts
buy = (DIPlus > DIMinus) and mfi_val > 50
sell = (DIMinus > DIPlus) and mfi_val > 50

plotshape(buy==1? buy : na, title="ADX Up", style=shape.square,location=location.top, color=color.green, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(sell==1? sell : na, title="ADX Down", style=shape.square,location=location.bottom, color=color.red, transp=0, size=size.tiny)

// Condition Alerts
alertcondition(buy==1 ? buy : na, title="Buy Alert", message="Buy, {{close}}")
alertcondition(sell==1 ? sell :na, title="Sell Alert", message="Sell, {{close}}")

//////////////////// DMI Finish
```

Comment: Thanks! It is workable as is, but I was hoping to only get the buy signal when the DMI crosses while the MFI is above 50. Currently the way written it also sends a buy signal if the net DMI is already positive and the MFI goes above 50. Ideally the signal is only send based on the DMI crossing if the MFI condition is already met.

Comment: Evening Brad Standige, I understand what you are after but can't at the moment figure it out. I will have a play. Hopefully another member can intervene.

Comment: I modified what you did just a little and at least have it working on one indicator. If the bottom is green and the top goes green, that is my buy signal :)

Comment: buy = (DIPlus > DIMinus)
sell = mfi_val > 50

plotshape(buy==1? buy : na, title="ADX Up", style=shape.square,location=location.top, color=color.green, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(sell==1? sell : na, title="ADX Down", style=shape.square,location=location.bottom, color=color.green, transp=0, size=size.tiny)

Answer (score 0):

I am quite a beginner on Pine script but I think the MFI is a built-in function and you don't need to have the details of the computation. This works in pine version 5.

```
//MFI computation

mfi_period = input(title="MFI Period", defval=14)
src = hlc3   
mf = ta.mfi(src, mfi_period)

//Plot
overbought=hline(80, title="Overbought", color=#787B86)
oversold=hline(20, title="Oversold", color=#787B86)
plot(mf, "MF", color=#7E57C2)
```

[Details on TradingView Pine manual for MFI function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dmfi)